# Editing a Question by the author

Tags: support, editing

A person asks a question and comments or answers are given for that answer by different people.But if the answers or comments are not satisfactory is it advisable to comment to each one what actually is required or should we edit the question completely?

Comment: I think we might need a bit of context: did the answers/comments here seem to address the question as posed, or were they at a tangent?

Comment: if the question itself is unclear, and it's recent, i'd first try to request clarification from the person who asked the question, pointing out the possible alternate interpretations, and asking which (if any) is meant.  i wouldn't edit it before a decisive clarification was provided.  (i *would* feel free to correct spelling and suchlike, if the meaning was clear, and only needed to be "untangled".)